# When would I need session_cache_expire and session_cache_limiter?

Tags: php, session

Looking over the manual pages for [session_cache_expire](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php) and [session_cache_limiter](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php), I'm a bit confused as to what these could possibly have to do with sessions. It seems to be that these control the hints sent to the browser as to how long to read a page from the local cache before re-requesting it, but how does that effect sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find http://shiflett.org/articles/how-to-avoid-page-has-expired-warnings interesting.

> Recap
>
> To avoid "Page Has Expired" warnings, set session.cache_limiter to private, and make sure that any form using the POST method submits to an intermediate processing page that redirects the user to a different URL.